Error response from daemon: open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/(LAYER-ID)/merged/(FILE-PATH): no such file or directory
I am trying to save a Docker image to a file using the command:
docker save IMAGE-NAME > FILE-NAME

I get the error message:
Error response from daemon: open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/(LAYER-ID)/merged/(FILE-PATH): no such file or directory

Obviously the layer LAYER-ID got corrupt somehow but I try to salvage the image. I tried to manually create the "missing" file in the layer, but Docker ignores my changes.
Is there a way to fix the layer by creating the missing file so that Docker does not ignore the fix? Is the contents of the layer stored somewhere?
Environment info

Version: 25.0.1
Storage Driver: overlay2
Linux (Ubuntu)


because its definately not programming related. Im going to guess and say you ran out of disk space.

@ChrisBecke right.

I don't know which SE site Docker questions properly belong on. Some are closer to SO, others split between ServerFault and DevOps.

It is impossible to change/patch the image or container layers because of the checksums. The contents of the layers are immutable. Trying to modify the layer content is a dead end.
I managed to salvage the container by exporting/importing the image. It is still necessary to build another image from the imported one to restore the startup command and environment variables.
Recap:

docker export IMAGE > FILE.img
docker import FILE.img TMPIMG
Create Docker file based on TMPIMG adding ports, variables and command.
docker build . -t FINALIMG

